# this code isn't printing as I want it to - python

Tags: python, function, printing

With this code,I am not getting
the kind of display I want.

```
def printTime(time):
    print time.hours,":",time.minutes,":",time.seconds,

def makeTime(seconds):
    time = Time()
    print "have started converting seconds into hours and minutes"
    time.hours = seconds/3600
    print "converted into hours and no.of hours is :",time.hours
    seconds = seconds - time.hours *3600
    print "number of seconds left now:",seconds
    time.minutes = seconds/60
    print "number of minutes now is :",time.minutes
    seconds = seconds - time.minutes*60
    print "number of seconds left now is :",seconds
    time.seconds = seconds
    print "total time now is:",printTime(time)
```

The last line is causing the problem that is:

```
print "total time now is:",printTime(time)
```

I want the result to be in the format below-
total time now is : 12:42:25

but what i get is
total time now is : 12:42:25 None

but when I write that line as:

```
print "total time now is:"
printTime(time)
```

then i get the result as -
total time now is :
 12:42:25

The None thing doesn't appear when I dont write
the printTime(time) function in the same line as print.

So,what's really happening here?

EDIT: I tried using the return statement, but the result was still the same. so,where exactly should I use the return statement. maybe i was using it incorrectly .
i tried doing it as

```
print "total time now is:",return printTime(time)
```

but this gives an error.

then I tried doing it this way -

```
print "total time now is:",printTime(time)
return printTime(time)
```

still get the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing the *return value* of the `printTime()` function.

All functions in Python have a return value, and if you don't use a `return` statement, that value defaults to `None`.

Instead of printing in the `printTime()` function, rename that function to `formatTime()` and have it return the formatted string:

```
def formatTime(time):
    return '{0.hours}:{0.minutes}:{0.seconds}'.format(time)
```

then use

```
print "total time now is:",formatTime(time)
```

The [`str.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) above uses a [format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) that refers to the first parameter passed in (`0`, python indexing is 0-based), and interpolates attributes from that parameter. The first parameter is your `time` instance.

You can expand on that and add some more formatting, such as zero-padding your numbers:

```
def formatTime(time):
    return '{0.hours:02d}:{0.minutes:02d}:{0.seconds:02d}'.format(time)
```

Comment: Hi Martijn, Your code works great, but I dont understand the use of '{0.hours}:{0.minutes}:{0.seconds}' here. could you explain a bit?
What's the 0 for? I was using time.minutes and time.hours instead.

Comment: @faraz: I expanded the answer a little; you could also use keyword arguments: `'{time.hours}:{time.minutes}:{time.seconds}'.format(time=time)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
I will also read up about format string syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`printTime` is returning a print function call, which you're then trying to print.

Change `printTime` to:

```
return time.hours + ":" + time.minutes + ":" + time.seconds
```

Or, more efficiently:

```
return "%s:%s:%s" % (time.hours, time.minutes, time.seconds)
```

Comment: Chad, the return time.hours + ":" + time.minutes + ":" + time.seconds line gives a type error : unsupported operand types.
while the second line works great.
now,I dont understand why is that happening?

Comment: @faraz, Oh, that's because `time.hours`, `time.minutes`, and `time.seconds` are returning integers (or some non-string value) and python can't concat string to non-strings.  So really the way to write that would be `return str(time.hours) + ":" + str(time.minutes)` etc.  But that is much less efficient due to the way python handles string concatenation, so I'd recommend the second line.